# Addressing more bytes than virtual address space (PTE size)

Tags: memory-management, virtual-memory

A computer system has a 36-bit virtual address space with a page size of 4K (small modification for hex representation), and 4 bytes per page table entry. (example found [here, 2nd problem](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~lorenzo/corsi/cs372/06F/hw/3sol.html))

PTE->0x11223344 (32 bits)

FullAddress(PTE<<12+PageOffset)->0x11223344AAA (44 bits)

But the offset in the page table cannot be bigger than 2^24 (36-PAGE_SIZE which is 12=24)

So, let's say there is a function f that generates the PTE address, f: {0,1}^24->{0,1}^32, which effectively allows access to 2^24 pages per process.

Bottom line, i would say that one process cannot address the full 2^44 bytes but only 2^36 and it could be potentially beneficial when there are multiple processes.

e.g. The system could allocate to 2^8 processes different chunks of 2^36 memory.

This is the potential benefit?

(This is for single level of page table, for multilevel it will grow even bigger)

I guess the question is similar with: Does Physical Address Extension (PAE) allows a process to utilize more than 4GB or does it just allows a number of processes to utilize more than 4GB?

Comment: I'm confused by the question.

Comment: Are you referring to any specific point? By the way my question is a question of the parameters that were stated in the referred link, which is about the usefulness of 4 byte PTE (We assume that the 4 byte is only the address without protection bits and other metadata)

Comment: I have edited the original post and added what i believe is an equivalent question